# Are there escape clauses that insurer can use to not pay claims if too many people die from Covid virus?

Tags: insurance, health-insurance, life-insurance

Are there any clauses in a insurance contract that allows an insurer to not pay claims if too many people die from Covid virus?

Is there a risk that insurance customers will be left out to dry?

Answer (score 2):

The insurance company could go bankrupt.

But a reputable insurance company will have their own insurance, called [reinsurance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinsurance), to protect their policy-holders and their investors from this possibility.

Comment: And if the re-insurer goes bankrupt?

Comment: @HartCO, you can't extract blood from a stone. But if reinsurers are going bankrupt, then very likely the loss is on a scale where the government is likely to step in.

Comment: And if the government goes bankrupt?

Comment: @glglgl, the government doesn't go bankrupt, it just prints more money, causing inflation, and reducing the real value of its debts.

Comment: @glglgl, at least if it's a government that controls its own currency and has debts denominated in that currency.